# Why the changes function does not return the changes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, activitylog

652/5000
I am using in my project of Laravel 5 the package https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog in its version 2.3. I have a page where I go through a list of activities and try to get the changes but it returns an empty array.

This is my Controller

```
public function history($id) {
     $incidence = Incidence::find($id);
     $activities = Activit::where('subject_id', $incidence->id)->get ();
     return view('incidence.history', compact('activities'));
}
```

This is my html page

```
@foreach ($activities as $activity)
   <p> {{ $activity->created_at }} </p>
   <p> {{ $activity->changes() }} </p>
@endforeach
```

And this is the output in the browser

[image: Picture]

Clarify that I have done 4 update to the same record which I see reflected in the activity_log table of the database that uses the package. But I do not understand why the arrangement of the changes is not shown as indicated by the site's documentation:

Calling $ activity-> changes will return this array:

```
[
   'attributes' => [
        'name' => 'updated name',
        'text' => 'Lorum',
    ],
    'old' => [
        'name' => 'original name',
        'text' => 'Lorum',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it uses a database table I'm certain this has to do with the way Laravel allows methods to be chained. When you do $activity->changes() it expects you to continue the query. IE: $activity->changes()->where('etc', 1)->get() or something similar. So by calling $activity->changes() you are just sending a partial query to eloquent.